# log4j2 logger config level does not override root logger level

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

According to [log4j documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html#:%7E:text=In%20example%205,must%20match%20exactly.), if I define a logger config for package `com.a.b.c` with level `ERROR` with root logger level set to `DEBUG`, only ERROR logs should come from classes in `com.a.b.c` while other classes should print `DEBUG` logs. Therefore I have the below log4j2-test.xml.

However, in my case `INFO` level logs from classes in `com.a.b.c` are still being printed. Did I misunderstand anything? What should I do to make classes in `com.a.b.c` print `ERROR` logs while all other classes print `INFO` logs?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" name="PropertiesConfig" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">target/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <ThresholdFilter level="trace"/>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %style{[%t]}{magenta} %highlight{%-5level}{TRACE=cyan, DEBUG=green, INFO=yellow, WARN=blue, ERROR=red} [%-60.60c] : %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <File name="fileLogger" fileName="${basePath}app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] : %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO" >
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleLogger" />
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.a.b.c" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleLogger" />
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Try change the order in Loggers. Put Root in last.

Comment: The `ERROR` threshold only applies to loggers, whose **name** start with "com.a.b.c". Usually classes use their fully qualified class name as logger name, but that does not need to be true (you can add both `%c` and `%C` to your pattern to see the difference).

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. The class in question is (weirdly) not using its own class name when getting the logger. Typically it is `LoggerFactory.getLogger(com.a.b.c)` but in my case the class is doing `LoggerFactory.getLogger(java.io.Console)`, thus our logger config `<Logger name="com.a.b.c" level="ERROR" additivity="false">` will not apply to logs coming from this class. I had to add a logger config for the class `java.io.Console`.